# Rdlc in ASP.NET MVC does not render properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am using ASP.NET MVC and i want to render an rdlc in a view.
Here is my code to render the rdlc file.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DepartmentwiseInwardOutwardReport(int? fd, int? td, string fdt, string tdt)
        {
            TrackBL trackBL = new TrackBL();
            IEnumerable<TrackModel> trackList = trackBL.GetDeptInwardOutwardReport(fd, td, fdt, tdt);
            //return PartialView("_TrackingSearchReport", trackList);
            LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
            localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/FileMovement.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("Customers", trackList);
            reportDataSource.Name = "FTSDataSet_proc_File_InwardOutWardReport";
            localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
            string reportType = "PDF";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;


            //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
            //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx

            string deviceInfo =
            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";



            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            //Render the report
            renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);

            //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NorthWindCustomers." + fileNameExtension);
            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

When i render this in the view, i am able to see 14 pages, i do have only 1 row to display as of now. two columns each are getting displayed in the page. I wanna display it like a report where all the columns are displayed next to other.
Am i missing some settings? ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Im using RDLC in MVC3 and even MVC4, I dont have that problem that you are facing, even though I think its related to the RDLC report itself, maybe you have the width of the page very high so its warping it to 14 pages (sometimes with me it warps to 3 pages if I forget to set the orientation and I have a large number of columns.

If you set width of your report to be larger than the page you try to print on, the report will be automatically split to fit pages.